# Apache-POI: Unable to write to an existing workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2010

I'm working on a project which needs to read an Excel Workbook, calls the necessary Web Services, and then takes the response from the webservices and enters that information in to the same Excel Workbook that was read.

Here is the error I'm seeing when trying to write to the Excel Workbook:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.io.IOException: Can't obtain the input stream from /docProps/app.xml
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:177)
at ext.ExcelProcessor.main(ExcelProcessor.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't obtain the input stream from /docProps/app.xml
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getInputStream(PackagePart.java:500)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties.<init>(POIXMLProperties.java:75)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:139)
    ... 2 more
```

Here is my code for the opening of the file/reading:

```
pkg = OPCPackage.open(xslFile);
    theWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

After this I read each row and extract each cell value.

Once this is done I'll create the cells under the headers for Success and Result Message and then do the following:

```
String sessionData = sessionKey[1];
                String[] cellValCurrRow = rowCellVals.get(r-1);
                String attachmentData[] = WQSServices.uploadAttachment(sessionData, cellValCurrRow);

                XSSFCell cell = xslRows[r].getCell(7);

                if(cell == null)
                {
                    cell = xslRows[r].createCell(7);
                }

                System.out.println("The Cell: "+cell.getStringCellValue());

                XSSFCell cell2 = xslRows[r].getCell(8);

                if(cell2 == null)
                {
                    cell2 = xslRows[r].createCell(8);
                }

                System.out.println("The Cell: "+cell2.getStringCellValue());

                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(attachmentData[0]);
                cell2.setCellValue(attachmentData[1]);

                System.out.println("New Cell Data: 1-"+cell.getStringCellValue()+" 2-"+cell2.getStringCellValue());

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(xslFile);
                theWorkbook.write(fos);
                fos.close();
```

Has anyone ran in to similar issue?

Comment: what jar files you add?did you have ooxml jar file included in classpath?

Comment: In my referenced libraries in Eclipse I have the following:
poi-3.8-20120326.jar
poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar
poi-excelant-3.8-2012032.jar
poi-ooxml-3.8-2012326.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-20120326.jar

Comment: k what about dom4j-1.6.1.jar star-api-1.0.1.jar and xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar files? I believe these are the dependencies of poi-ooxml jar files

Comment: Do you mean stax-api-1.0.1.jar if so, I have all 3.

Comment: [Workaround for my issue which fixed my problems][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9792406/1231715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current issue listed is a bug that has been around since 2010 and can be found @ https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49940

In the stackoverflow listing below a workaround was found that if you close and re-open the book again before doing another write out to the file it will work without issue.  This isn't efficient by any means but it does fix the issue until the Apache-POI Dev Team figures out the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792406/1231715

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error message but had used different classes. Current poi version I'm using is poi-ooxml 3.9 but it still has the issue. Now I fixed my problem and I think this problem arises when you obtain Workbook instance at first.

When I write data to the file, I do like this (with practice rules for exceptions and close):

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();
```

I got "Can't obtain the input stream from /docProps/app.xml" error message, when I obtained Workbook instance like this:

```
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(filePath));
```

When I fixed the problem, modified code was

```
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

In my case it doesn't matter whether you open and read from and write to the same file, or read from one file then write to another. If you read the poi source codes, you could see the factory methods I used might call open() methods in OPCPackage class. Try using the method getting InputStream as its argument.

Comment: Great! The worst is that I had working code, then I have read that WorkbookFactory.create() was less resource intensive with a File than with a Stream, so I changed, and got this strange error...

Comment: cit. @Bankie: "Current poi version I'm using is poi-ooxml 3.9 but it still has the issue.". I'm using 3.17 and it has this issue as well

Answer (score 2):

Here is how this can be done when using OPCPackage to read  (try/catch/finally ommitted for readibility):

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open("existingFile.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(pkg);
```

> make your modifications...
>      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
>      ...

```
fos = new FileOutputStream("outputFileName.xlsx");
wb.write(fos);
pkg.close();
fos.close();
Faces.sendFile(new File(outputFileName)
```

The comment above from Jayamohan helped me solve this problem today (using different file path for Input and for Output). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are using the same filePath `xslFile` for
opening and saving the file.

Opening the file,

```
pkg = OPCPackage.open(xslFile);
    theWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

Saving the file,

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(xslFile);
theWorkbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

You need an InputStream for read and work with your file, but this
stream becames unaccessible when you create an
OutputStream under the same path and file name.

Comment: No, it does work. I have tried it. There is no problem with the OP's code as per my knowledge. opening the file for reading does not lick it and any program can write to it even if it is open in read mode by other program

Comment: This was posted by an admin from the apache-poi group:
If a workbook is created from an instance of the OPCPackage class, the OPCPacakge instance must not be disposed of until after the workbook has been written. This change the the code, removed the problem completely;

org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage opc = 
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(filename);
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook wb =
new org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(opc);
java.io.FileOutputStream fileOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filename);
wb.write(fileOut);
opc.close();
fileOut.close();

Comment: This is was commentary based off another bug but it does surround my issue.  https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53613

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found for this, and I've been looking for a while, is to make sure you don't open your `Workbook` with the `File` which you use to open the `FileOutputStream` to save the `Workbook`. Instead, use a `FileInputStream` to open the `Workbook`.

Something like this will work flawlessly

```
        File inputFile = new File("Your-Path");
        this.inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        this.opc = OPCPackage.open(this.inputStream);
        this.workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(opc);

...

        this.outputStream = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
        this.workbook.write(this,outputStream);
```

Don't forget to close every opened stream and the `OPCPackage`.

Comment: This would have the downside of increasing the memory footprint though

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the same file is opened again before closing before.

```
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream("file.xlsx");
FileOutputStream file2 = new FileOutputStream("file.xlsx");
file2.close();
file1.close();
```

This code will throws this error.

Solution:

```
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream("file.xlsx");
file1.close();
FileOutputStream file2 = new FileOutputStream("file.xlsx");
file2.close();
```