# Error while using POI API

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am using selenium webdriver. I am writing to excel file using POI API.
 I am getting following error:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1258)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTXfImpl.getXfId(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.getStyleAt(StylesTable.java:183)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellStyle(XSSFCell.java:427)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellStyle(XSSFCell.java:63)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(DateUtil.java:280)
at com.bcatman.util.Xls_Reader.getCellData(Xls_Reader.java:149)
at com.bcatman.base.TestBase.readExcelData(TestBase.java:159)
at com.bcatman.suite.CatalogImportExport.ImportSimpleExcel.testcaseImportSimpleExcel(ImportSimpleExcel.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a newer version of Apache POI? eg the latest, which is currently 3.11?

Comment: You read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253653/exception-when-writing-to-the-xlsx-document-several-times-using-apache-poi-3-7

Comment: Selenium is completely irrelevant to your problem. However, showing some of your code would be quite relevant!